# How to load inners related entities when performing left outer join

Tags: entity-framework

.Net Framework 4.8 and EF 6

When running the following query, the left outer join works as expected.
The only issue is that `Inners.Include(e => e.Related1).Include(e => e.Related2)` doesn't load the related entries. `Inners.Related1` and `Inners.Related2` are null.

```
 _context.Lefts
        .GroupJoin(_context.Inners.Include(e => e.Related1).Include(e => e.Related2),
            left => left.Key,
            inner => inner.LeftId,
            (l, i) => new { Left = l, Inner = i })
        .SelectMany(x => x.Inner.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (x, i) => new { Left = x.Left, Inner = e })
        .ToArray();
```

How can I perform a left outer join and load related entities of the inner part?